# How can I add two columns to my data set in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a data set with 4 columns and want to count the number of times that the value in column 2 was equal to the value in one of the rows in column 0 and also the number of times that the value in column 3 was equal to the value in one of the rows in column 0. Also I want to filter the data based on the value in column 1.
Here is an example:

```
|0        |1        |2        |3        |
-----------------------------------------
|a        |post     |b        |c        |
|x        |share    |a        |d        |
|b        |post     |a        |l        |
|d        |post     |N/A      |a        |
-----------------------------------------
```

the result should look like this:

```
|0        |1        |2        |3        |4        |5        |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|a        |post     |b        |c        |2        |1        |
|b        |post     |a        |l        |1        |0        |
|d        |post     |N/A      |a        |0        |1        |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Therefore I need to add two columns to my data set. My initial thought is that I can use nested query. Here's my code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
select t.*,
  (select count(*) from 
  (
  select t.*,
  (select count(*) from tab where [2] = t.[0]) [4] 
  from tab t
  )


 where [3] = t.[0]) [5] 
  from tab t
)
WHERE [1] = 'post'
```

but the the result of my query does not return column 4. Can you help me figure out the problem with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query contains almost the correct code:

```
select 
  t.*,
  (select count(*) from tab where [2] = t.[0]) [4],
  (select count(*) from tab where [3] = t.[0]) [5]
from tab t
where t.[1] = 'post'
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jM2sbRqTWKqe7Xz2V8ac7H/1).
Results:

```
| 0   | 1    | 2   | 3   | 4   | 5   |
| --- | ---- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a   | post | b   | c   | 2   | 1   |
| b   | post | a   | l   | 1   | 0   |
| d   | post | N/A | a   | 0   | 1   |
```

Comment: this works. Thanks. I have a question, though. I expect the number of rows to be equal to the number of times "post" appears in column 1. Is that right? In other words and considering example above, the number of rows reduced from 4 to 3, because "post" appeared three times in column 1. Can anything else effect the number of rows?

Comment: This is what you have in your code: `WHERE [1] = 'post'`

Comment: I had mistakenly used ```where``` twice. your code works perfectly fine. thanks!

Comment: You use my query as it is now, right? Not as I first posted it. I don't believe there is a difference. Run `select count(*) from tab where [1] = 'post'` and `select count(*) from (<my query here>)`. Both should return the same number. The WHERE clause is the same in both.